# Why when I try to update UEFI FW I get "Please make sure the flash is not write protected"?

Tags: windows-10, uefi

I'm a user of the Minnowboard MAX from Intel which brings UEFI as the boot manager. In order to test different OS (32 and 64 bit) I need to change the FW of the UEFI from 64 to 32 and viceversa.

At first, I updated the FW of the Minnowboard from 64 bit to 32 bit without any problem, as described in Minnowboard documentation. After this I installed Windows 10 32 bit, but when I tried to go back to a 64 bit OS, when I send the command to change from 32 bit to 64 I get the following message:

"Update Failed. Please make sure the flash is not write protected"

I do not remember setting any flash protection, at least consciously. Any idea how to solve it?

I installed UEFI FW version [0.96](https://firmware.intel.com/projects/minnowboard-max) .

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "when I send the command to change from 32 bit to 64" - what command? Please give more details and some screenshots.

Comment: I save the files in a USB, then I plug in to the Minnowboard. I open the UEFI shell and the USB is mapped in FS1. I use "FS1:". When I need to change from the 64 bit to 32 bit OS I write the following: MinnowBoard.MAX.FirmwareUpdateIA32.efi MNW2MAX1.X64.0096.R01.1706301843.bin